# nginx one domain few websites

Tags: php, nginx

I am having problem with configuration of nginx for few pages on one domain. For example we have example.com. This page allows u to buy some goods, but I would like to seperate pages for continents. So I created
/usr/share/nginx/europe, /usr/share/nginx/asia each folder have it owns files, database etc. I am trying to configurate it but i dunno know how.
Should I make some subdomains instead? Cannot I use for example:
example.com/asia example.com/europe
in /etc/nging/sites-enabled I ve created two files europe and asia:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/europe; 
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com/europe;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test1_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test1_error.log;

    location /blog.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

server {
    listen   80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/asia; 
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com/asia;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/asia_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/asia_error.log;

    location /blog.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```